# MATLAB Linux Out of memory error

Tags: linux, matlab

We are running a large MATLAB program. After about 24 hours of calculation it stops with an "Out of Memory" error.

Not long before this error occured the process status was quite healty, the process using about 3 Gb on a 12 Gb RAM machine with 32 Gb swap. We have no reason to believe that the process should behave much different, it was in iteration 3 of similar process where the first three iterations lead to a VmPeak of 2.7 Gb. The process was run without GUI using the -nojvm option, using MATLAB r2013a. The error occured in two different computers. Depending on exact parameterization the error occurs at different places in the program.

My question is: is there in MATLAB/Linux/64 bit another resource than plain RAM which can link to an Out of Memory message? Can it be memory fragmentation related, and how can we measure the current level of memory fragmentation?

Matlab error:

```
CATCH in vsProcessVideosetByFrame.Error using cat
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ttClassDetections/horzcat (line 170)
            output.data.(fn{j}) = cat(2,temp{:});
```

Process status not long before it crashed with an Out of Memory message:

```
schuttek@pc-07843:~$ cat /proc/14123/status
Name:   MATLAB
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   14123
Ngid:   0
Pid:    14123
PPid:   1
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    8793    8793    8793    8793
Gid:    100     100     100     100
FDSize: 256
Groups: 4 24 27 30 46 100 108 124 501
NStgid: 14123
NSpid:  14123
NSpgid: 14123
NSsid:  11423
VmPeak:  2744640 kB
VmSize:  2613568 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:   1045376 kB
VmRSS:   1025692 kB
VmData:  2095720 kB
VmStk:       132 kB
VmExe:        12 kB
VmLib:    179980 kB
VmPTE:      2920 kB
VmPMD:        24 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
HugetlbPages:          0 kB
Threads:        18
SigQ:   1/64005
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000008080006
SigIgn: 0000000000000001
SigCgt: 00000001880804ee
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
Seccomp:        0
Cpus_allowed:   ffffffff
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-31
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:      0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:        37
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     5
```

Comment: Do a `dmesg | grep -i kill`, OOM killer usually writes something when terminating an offending program

Comment: It might also be helpful if you were to post the original MATLAB error

Comment: Original MATLAB error added.

Comment: dmesg | grep -i kill results in no output. I don't believe the system experienced an out of memory condition.

Comment: You say: "Depending on exact parameterization the error occurs at different places in the program." Do you mean it errors at the same line of code but after different numbers of iterations, or at different lines of code (but always within iteration 3)?

Comment: Depending on parameterization the error occurs at different lines and in different iterations. We never saw it in early iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is probably not the OOM killer (as `dmesg | grep kill` is empty), the error should be internal to MATLAB.

One possible cause is indeed the memory fragmentation; at least some MATLAB routines seem to request explicitly continuous areas of memory that you may run out of. That may be alleviated with `pack` - a MATLAB function that reconciles the memory.

Here's the documentation page. Make sure to heed the warning about variables larger than 2GB!

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pack.html

Answer (score 0):

So far running on a Windows 10 64 bit system seems to solve our problem.